# Composite sorting on Slick.Dataview

Tags: slickgrid

I am new to slickgrid, in my application  i am using slick.dataview to show grid data.

There is a need to have composite sorting on specified columns using Slick.Dataview.

I have used column wise  sorting, It works fine. Similarly i need to do for group of columns.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Please help me to handle this in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `sort` function that sorts on more than one column.
For example in [example4-model.html](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html), to sort on *percentComplete* and then *start*, you could use

```
function percentCompleteSort(a, b) {
  var rtn = a["percentComplete"] - b["percentComplete"];
  if (rtn !== 0) return rtn;
  return a["start"] - b["start"];
}
```